# Replacement for minimumFontSize for a UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uilabel, sizetofit

I'm aware of minimumScaleFactor but it isn't useful for the result I'm after.

I have two UILabels and I want them both to be the same size. I want them to fit to the label's view if possible down to a minimum size and then I'll do a check to set them both to the smallest font size, so that they both fit and are both the same size.

I don't think I can achieve this using minimumScaleFactor because it doesn't seem to actually change the font size, it seems to use some sort of scaling on the view (correct me if I'm wrong). I don't seem to be able to set this scale manually other than setting it's minimum value so it seems to be useless in my circumstances.

Answer (score -1):

Set `max_msg_height` that you want in your cell. This function will check if your message length is more than `max_mgs_height` and font size and if it is greater than 12 points, it will continue. In my case i have set `max_msg_height = 160`. Default font size to 16. So, if I got message which is not adjust in lable frame then I reduce font by 1 point by using this while loop as shown below:

```
while (messageLbl.frame.size.height > max_msg_height &&
       messageLbl.font.pointSize>12) {
    messageLbl.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:messageLbl.font.pointSize-1];
    [messageLbl sizeToFit];
}
```

Comment: And what exactly is your code meant to do? Please explain your code and don't just paste code in.

Comment: This will change the height of the UILabel. My post was asking about how to change the font size so it fits into a label. The label itself should not change size.

Comment: set max_msg_height that you want in your cell. This function will check if your message lenght is more than max_mgs_height and font size is greate than 12 point, it will continue. In my case i have set max_msg_height = 160. Default font size to 16. So, if i got message which is not adjust in lable frame then i reduce font by 1 point by using this while loop.